# If no universal set is defined, is it the union of all sets presented?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm completely new to set theory and not strongly numerate, and have just learned about the concepts of union, intersection, complement, relative complement, universal and empty set. So I would appreciate patience and simple explanations in answers. I've also never used MathJax or set notation before so if there are typos please excuse or help me correct.

My question is this. After learning about these concepts and in particular De Morgan's Law, which states that $(A \cup B)' = A' \cap B'$, I was trying to understand this intuitively using examples. Where I fell down is understanding the complement and what the "universal set" is.

I was trying to understand this intuitively using two example sets. Say

$A = \{1, 2, 3\}$

$B = \{3, 5, 6\}$

Then:

$A \cup B = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 6\}$

$A \cap B = \{3\}$

But my confusion is then how to find the **complement** of either set. From what I understand, the complement is everything in the universal set which is not in the set itself. And the "universal set" is not "everything in the world", but rather every element in the problem space (e.g. for "All even numbers up to 10", $U = \{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\}$)

But in this scenario, **what is the universal set, as I haven't defined one**? Is it simply the union of all sets presented, i.e. $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6\}$? In which case, the complement of A or $A' = \{5, 6\}$ and $B' = \{1, 2\}$

So then it would follow that:

$A' \cap B' = \emptyset$ (as they have nothing in common)

$(A \cup B)' = \emptyset$ (as the union of $A$ and $B$ is $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6\}$, the complement of that union is everything not in the universal set. If the universal set is also $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6\}$, then that complement is nothing.)

Is this working of De Morgan's correct, or have I made a faulty assumption about the universal set?

To reiterate, the basic question I'm asking is: without a "defined" universal set, is it simply the union of all given sets?

Comment: Thank you for your improvements to the set notation Matthias :)

Comment: Correct; without "universal" set we have to assume some "domain" that include all elements of the sets that we are dealing with. Thus, with ref to your example, we may assume a "huge" domain: $\mathbb N$, or a "slim" one, e.g. $\text {domain} = \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 \}$.

Comment: If you assume as domain the "minimal" one: $\{ 1,2,3,5,6, \}$ your "computation" is fine: $(A \cup B)' = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De Morgan's laws hold for any set $U$ that contains the specified sets $A$ and $B.$

In other words, what De Morgan's laws say is that for any set $U$ and subsets $A, B$ of $U,$ we have
$$(A \cup B)^{c} = A^{c} \cap B^{c}$$ and
$$(A \cap B)^{c} = A^{c} \cup B^{c}$$
(where $A^c$ denotes the complement of $A$ with respect to the set $U$).

So, the power of De Morgan's laws is that they hold not just for any specific universal set, but that they hold for any universal set $U$ (where "universal" here really just means that $U$ contains both $A$ and $B$).

Let's look at the example you gave, where
$$A = \{1, 2, 3\}$$ and
$$B = \{3, 5, 6\}.$$ One choice for the set $U$ is to take $$U = A\cup B = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 6\},$$ as you did in the problem. Then, as you verified in the problem statement, De Morgan's laws hold.

But we can do this for a different choice of universal set $U$ as well! For example, let $$U = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}.$$ Then, we have
$$A^{c} = \{4, 5, 6, 7\},$$
$$B^{c} = \{1, 2, 4, 7\},$$ hence we have
$$A^{c} \cup B^{c} = \{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$$ and
$$A^{c} \cap B^{c} = \{4, 7\}.$$

Then, note that
$$(A \cup B)^{c} = (\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6\})^{c} = \{4, 7\} = A^{c} \cap B^{c}$$
and
$$(A \cap B)^{c} = (\{3\})^{c} = \{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7\} = A^{c} \cup B^{c},$$ so De Morgan's laws hold for this choice of $U$ as well.

If you really want to prove De Morgan's laws, you will need to treat the sets abstractly, but I hope this example has helped show that we are not working with a specific universal set.

Comment: Brilliant answer. You've both cleared up the basic assumption, that we can assume a minimal universal set of the union set of A and B in the example, and helped me understand that De Morgan's holds with a different universal set - with a simple explanation that matches my current level of understanding. Thank you!

Comment: Is it reasonable to say that the universal set can be anything for De Morgan's to hold? Even if it's {1, 2, 3, 4, indigo, apple, dog, cat} etc., that (A∪B)c=Ac∩Bc?

Comment: @Lou Yes, De Morgan's Laws would still hold, as long as $A, B$ are subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, 4,$ indigo, apple, dog, cat$\}$.

Comment: Ah, that's the caveat I was wondering about. Thanks again!